# Ionic iframe issue when opening an external link

Tags: ionic-framework, iframe, ionic3

I am trying to use an `iframe` inside my hybrid app. The `iframe` works perfectly, but it as some links inside that won't open when you click on them specifically when they are deployed to the iOS platform. It works in the browser view, but not in the iOS device. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I'm also having trouble with this. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your confix.xml and try it.

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have those things, and also this: 
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
 in my config.xml file, but it is not solving the issue. 

Do you know of any other possible solutions?